# Strange issue with mysql query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have the following content saved in the mysql db under table default_pages_content.The column type is 'longtext'. The php framework is codeigniter.

```
<img alt="" class="image alignment-none" data-image="true" src="{{ url:site }}files/large/75ce5eda6536423" />
```

Now when I do a select query and print the resultset in the browser it doesn't pickup the above content.But when I do the same query in phpmyadmin then I get the column content.

My query is

```
$selectcustom = "SELECT * FROM `default_pages_".$row['slug']."` 
                 WHERE id=".$row['entry_id'];
$custom_content = $this->db->query($selectcustom)->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$selectcustom = "SELECT * FROM `default_pages_".$row['slug']."` 
                 WHERE id='".$row['entry_id']."';";
$custom_content = $this->db->query($selectcustom)->result_array();
```

It's been a very long time but i remember codeigniter having some odd issues with how you write your queries. Also have you checked to make sure $row contains the values you think it does?

Another way to check is to write an inline query and check if that works so you can narrow it down to how you have written it... test like such.

```
$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_pages_stuff;")->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to check you db query is right or wrong,for this you have to write a code in your model after your db query.

`print_r($this->db->last_query());`